# circuitikz and ConTeXT

Tags: context, circuitikz

I would like to use `circuitikz` with ConTeXT but I have an error message, `! Undefined control sequence.`

My code is:

```
\usemodule[tikz] 

\usemodule[circuitikz][european]

\starttext

\startcircuitikz

\draw (0,0) to[R, l=$R_1$] (2,0);

\stopcircuitikz

\stoptext
```

A solution is proposed in a `circuitikz` manual:

> " In actually using CircuiTikZ with TikZ version 2 in ConTEXt an error
>   comes up, saying something like
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \tikz@cc@mid@checks ->
>   \pgfutil@ifnextchar!

The solution has been suggested to me by Aditya Mahajan, and involves modifying a file in TikZ:

Here is the fix. In `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex` change

```
\def\tikz@cc@mid@checks{
   \pgfutil@ifnextchar !{%AM: Added space
     \tikz@cc@mid%
   }{%
     \advance\pgf@xa by\tikz@cc@factor\pgf@xb%
     \advance\pgf@ya by\tikz@cc@factor\pgf@yb%
     \tikz@cc@parse% continue
}% }
\def\tikz@cc@mid !{%AM Added space
   \pgfutil@ifnextchar({%
     \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@cc@project%
4
}{%
     \tikz@cc@mid@num%
   }%
} "
```

I need to modify a file in TikZ but I don't know where I can find this file and i don't understand what I need to change in this file.

Thank you for your help.

Mecadict

Comment: It would be better to update your TeX distribution so that you are no longer using version 2 of TikZ. If I've understood what you are saying correctly.

Comment: Not that it works with TikZ 3 either....

Comment: Please include a link to the source of the solution you mention.

Comment: That code no longer appears to be present in the current version of the file.

Comment: The basic problem is that tikz assumes that `!` has catcode `other`, while ConTeXt is assuming that `!` has catcode `letter`. You can grep the TikZ/circuitTikZ code base for `pgfutil@ifnextchar!` and replace that with `pgfutil@ifnextchar !` (note additional space)

Comment: Thank you Aditya. But I don't find circuitTikZ code base (tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)...

Comment: It is not clear to me: is this a general problem with TikZ/ConTeXt compatibility? Or is it specific to **circuitikz**?

Comment: @Aditya Still? Doesn't TikZ now test for that? I can;t see an obvious assumption in that code in recent versions but I can see it in the 2012 version.

Comment: @cfr, Last time I checked (a couple of months ago), TikZ still changes catcodes manually rather than using the ConTeXt catcode tables. I checked circtuitikz, and it is also changing catcodes manually. Nonetheless, most (all?) of the functionality works.

Comment: Looking at the code, the `t-circuitikz` module doesn't check argument options (because in ConTeXt, you cannot mix key-value and argument options (i.e, `european, current=american`)).

Comment: @Aditya I don't know what ConTeXt does. But `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex` only seems to use `pgfutil@ifnextchar!` after running certain checks. In particular `\def\tikz@cc@mid@checks` is not as quoted in the question. Whether this is sufficient, I don't know. But it is checking catcodes and grouping changes. Whereas the older code was not using these kinds of checks and I took it that the space fix was intended to fix that older code. (Indeed, you can't use it without modification to fix the current code, because the original lines no longer exist.)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could just set the options you want individually, since `european` is simply a shorthand for a collection of such options. For example:

```
\usemodule[circuitikz]
\ctikzset{current=european, voltage=european, resistor=european, inductor=european}

\starttext

\starttikzpicture

\draw (0,0) to[R, l=$R_1$] (2,0);

\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image: European]

Comment: Sorry but when I try with your code, I have an error : "error on line 16 in file /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/circuittikz/t-circuittikz.tex: ! Missing \endcsname inserted"

Comment: I'm using TeX Live 2015. I don't know if that is the difference, but the code works OK for me. Do you get an error with just my example?

Comment: The code runs okay for me as well (latest context beta plus latest circuitikz downloaded from ctan).

Comment: I have updated my version of TexLive and now, the code runs okay. I didn't find the circuitTikZ code base in the precedent version of TexLive to modify the code as Aditya has suggested...  Thank you very much for your help, my problem is solved. And sorry for my ignorance of ConTeXT : i'm a beginner !  ;)

Comment: But I believe that there is others problems with photodiode for example.

Comment: For example, with photodiode, arrow doesn't appears. The error message is : "Unknown arrow tip kind 'latex'"

Comment: @Mecadict Doesn't it load the `arrows` library? It should do if it uses arrow tips from that library.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `circuitikz` module does not acknowledge a plain `european` option.  It rather takes a `key=value` list, akin to `\ctikzset`.  Therefore, to obtain the european resistor, one has to pass `resistor=european` to the module.  Also, you *have* to load the `tikz` module before circuitikz or the keys will no be parsed (I guess they are being silently forwarded to `tikz` which simply discards them).

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[circuitikz][resistor=european]
\starttext
\startcircuitikz
  \draw (0,0) to[R, l=$R_1$] (2,0);
\stopcircuitikz
\stoptext
```

[image]